# Генерация случайного числа без повторений из выбранного диапазона

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую возможность - при нажатии на кнопку генерируется случайное число из диапазона. Но полностью такого функционала достичь не получается - или есть повторы или приходится 2-3 раза нажимать на кнопку.
Что можно сделать, что бы заработало так, как мне нужно?

```
    int random;
    HashSet<Integer> set_ofuseNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    private int GeneratorNumber(){
        random = (int) (1 + Math.random()*5);
        return random;
    }// генерация случайно число  от 1 до 5

    public void AddToList(View v){
        this.a = GeneratorNumber(); //генерируем число
        set_ofuseNumbers.add(this.a); //добавляем в хешСет
        viewText.setText(""+ this.a); // выводим на экран
        Log.d("seek", String.valueOf(set_ofuseNumbers)); //выводим в лог
        if (set_ofuseNumbers.contains(this.a)){
            GeneratorNumber(); //генерируем число
            Toast.makeText(this, "повтор", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(set_ofuseNumbers.size()==5){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Заполненно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // проверка заполненности листа.
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте массив или список чисел нужного диапазона, и примените [перемешивание Фишера-Йетса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) - функцию несложно написать вручную или применить `Collections.shuffle`

Если диапазон очень велик, а чисел извлекать нужно немного - вот тогда можно применить метод генерации случайного числа в цикле, пока не сгенерируется то, что отсутствует в наборе использованных